# Having both a method and a function which do the same thing?

Tags: python, function, methods

Is there a convention on how to have both a method and a function that do the same thing (or whether to do this at all)?

Consider, for example,

```
from random import choice
from collections import Counter

class MyDie:
    def __init__(self, smallest, largest, how_many_rolls):
        self.min = smallest
        self.max = largest
        self.number_of_rolls = how_many_rolls

    def __call__(self):
        return choice( range(self.min, self.max+1) )

    def count_values(self):
        return Counter([self() for n in range(self.number_of_rolls)])

def count_values(randoms_func, number_of_values):
    return Counter([randoms_func() for n in range(number_of_values)])
```

where `count_values` is both a method and a function.

I think it's nice to have the method because the result "belongs to" the MyDie object.  Also, the method can pull attributes from the `MyDie` object without having to pass them to `count_values`.  On the other hand, it's nice to have the function in order to operate on functions other than `MyDie`, like

```
count_values(lambda: choice([3,5]) + choice([7,9]), 7)
```

Is it best to do this as above (where the code is repeated; assume the function is a longer piece of code, not just one line) or replace the `count_values` method with

```
def count_values(self):
    return count_values(self, number_of_rolls)
```

or just get rid of the method all together and just have a function?  Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that still allows you to encapsulate the logic in `MyDie`. Create a class method in `MyDie`

```
@staticmethod
def count_specified_values(random_func, number_of_values):
   return Counter([randoms_func() for n in range(number_of_values)])
```

You also could add additional formal parameters to the constructor with default values that you could override to achieve the same functionality.